# Import blob/table data from storage account in excel using organizational account credentials

Tags: excel, azure, import

My goal is to import data from a storage account (blob or table) with excel without using the account key. Therefore I tried to import the data via Odata or Web. When I try to connect I can login with Anonymous, Windows, Basic, Web API and organizational account. Nevertheless, when I try to login with my organizational account it says that it is unable to connect because this credential type is not supported for this resource. Is there a way to import blob/table data from the storage account using the AD credentials and without using the key1, key2 or SAS? Also, looked into using Storage Blob Delegator as a role (so users can create their own SAS), but that seems only to work for blob containers and not for tables.